# How to build/host an AngularJS application with Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

My simple AngularJS app looks like this:

```
angularApp
    |___lib
    |___scripts
    |       |___app.js
    |       |___controller1.js
    |___styles
    |___index.html
    |___view1.html
```

It runs local on my system with webStorm...

**Now my question is, what I have to do so my angularApp will run online on Parse Cloud Code?**
**Please could anyone show me a simple example or give me a rough plan of how to setup a simple AngularJS app with Parse Cloud Code...**

A HelloWorld example I have successfully deployed on Parse Cloud Code and it is online!:-)
But my AngularJS app isn't running on Parse Cloud Code and somehow I have no real plan what I have to do... :-( 
My search for examples was unsuccessful!

Answer (score 1):

OMG, it is so easy... 
I only have to navigate to the public folder of the parse cloud code project and paste my AngularJS project files.

Then it looks like this:

```
Cloud Directory
    |___cloud
    |___public
          |___lib
          |___scripts
          |      |___app.js
          |      |___controller1.js
          |___styles
          |___index.html
          |___view1.html
```

Finally 'parse deploy' and it works... :-) OMG it is soooo easy! ^^